# Possible typo in openwebbeans.properties in openejb-core.jar?

Tags: apache-tomee, openejb, openwebbeans, tomee-8

I had been dealing with a deployment issue in a recent TomEE version (8.0.11) that I could not make sense of, to which I finally found a workaround but not quite sure about the integrity of the solution.

Before getting into details, I'd like to state that I tried to open an issue in the official repo but it seems they accept only pull requests and since I am not quite sure about the drill, I figured I'd just report it here for some visibility until a PR is made, if necessary.

So during a traditional EJB deployment I got a ClassNotFoundException which suggests some incorrect packaging:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.webbeans.el.el22.EL22Adaptor not found
```

After digging out the offending row by the source code, I found out that the class FQN is obtained from the file `META-INF/openwebbeans/openwebbeans.properties` file that ships within the `openejb-core` archive.

```
...
################################### Default EL Adaptor ####################################
#Default implementation oforg.apache.webbeans.spi.adaptor.ELAdaptor
org.apache.webbeans.spi.adaptor.ELAdaptor=org.apache.webbeans.el.el22.EL22Adaptor
################################################################################################
...
```

But the class FQN `org.apache.webbeans.el.el22.EL22Adaptor` is nowhere to be found in the [tomee project](https://github.com/apache/tomee/).

The only `org.apache.webbeans.spi.adaptor.ELAdaptor` implementation in the openwebbeans project is `org.apache.webbeans.el22.EL22Adaptor` that is, without the 'el' package in the middle.

The same problem is present in the openejb repository at below link as well:
https://github.com/apache/openejb/blob/trunk/openejb/container/openejb-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/openwebbeans/openwebbeans.properties

However, when I check the current openwebbeans repo in github, it does not seem to have the typo:
https://github.com/apache/openwebbeans/blob/master/webbeans-el22/src/main/resources/META-INF/openwebbeans/openwebbeans.properties

It booted up as expected after I modified the openejb-core.jar inside under tomee/lib directory, but this is not future proof obviously.

I am wondering if this is an honest mistake or a packaging error, but I sure hope that it will be fixed soon.

Comment: TomEE uses jira.apache.org as bug tracker.

Comment: Most probably it was forgotten to be adjusted on our side but needs a careful look. A Jira issue would help to track and we can ensure to have a look :)

Comment: In addition, the link points to an old repository, which isn't maintained/used anymore. The code ist located here https://github.com/apache/tomee/tree/tomee-8.x

Comment: I'd love to open a jira issue at the said tracker. Thanks for the pointer @rzo1 !

Comment: An issue is created in the related tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-4101

Comment: @rzo1 Created a PR with id https://github.com/apache/tomee/pull/951